# Possible to associate Elastic IP to an instance without immediately losing public ip?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, dns

I have a windows EC2 instance running a production website and DNS is configured to have my domain name point to its public IP.  There is currently no Elastic IP (EIP) associated with the instance.  I would like to start using a Elastic IP and have my domain name point to it instead of the public IP (which can change if I ever have to change the instance).

Reading the documentation I find this statement troubling:

> When you associate an EIP with an instance, the instance's current
>   public IP address is released to the EC2-Classic public IP address
>   pool.

My fear is this:

- I assign an EIP to the instance and the public IP is released.
- Now my website no longer works, because the domain name points to the public IP, which is no longer associated with my EC2 instance.
- I must then point DNS records to the EIP.  But this could take up to 48 hours for propagation to take place (i.e. my site may be be unreachable for up to 48 hours).

How can I do this without having to live through DNS propagation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your EC2 instance is in a VPC, you can add a second network interface onto your EC2 instance. You can associate your Elastic IP address with that second network interface. This way, your EC2 instance could respond to both IP addresses.

**Instructions**

1. Create a new Network Interface in the same subnet as your EC2 instance.
2. Allocate a new Elastic IP for your VPC (if you haven't done so already).
3. Associate the Elastic IP address with your new Network Interface (eni).
4. Attach your new Network Interface to your EC2 instance.

Do not change your DNS yet.

You may need to RDP/SSH into your EC2 instance to make some configuration changes to ensure your EC2 instance responds correctly to the new IP address.

Modify the hosts file on your local computer to test connecting to your website via the new IP address.

When that works, do the DNS switch and restore your hosts file.

Comment: Yes - I believe it is in a VPC.  In the EC2 console it has a "VPC ID": vpc-76930813.  So I guess this explains how it was able to have different Elastic IP from the Public IP (see my comment to @rodolk).  How do I go about this?  If I recall correctly, in the past I created an EIP and associated it with the EC2.  Then I could access by both Public and EIP.  Is this all I do?  Sorry - just want to get this right.  It was not long ago when I messed up DNS and brought site down for 48hours.

Comment: Perfect.  Great instructions too.  This must have what I had done in the past (but not knowing what I was doing).  So once ample time has passed (i.e. 48 hours) after DNS propagation, should I remove the network interface associated with the public IP?  Do you get charged more for having 2 network interfaces?

Comment: You are only charged for unused Elastic IP addresses and "secondary" Elastic IP addresses. You are not charged for Network Interfaces.

Comment: You cannot detach the primary Network Interface. Instead, after 48 hours, move the Elastic IP address from your secondary ENI to your Instance (or primary ENI). Then detach your secondary ENI.

Answer (score 3):

48 to 72 hours before your pre-determined switch-over time, reduce the time-to-live (TTL) on your DNS entry to 300 seconds (5 minutes).

At your designated switch-over time:

1. Attach the Elastic IP address
2. Update your DNS entry to point to your Elastic IP address

Doing this, your effective "downtime" is reduced to 5 minutes.

Comment: Thanks,  I don't know enough about DNS.  So by setting TTL to this value are the DNS servers in essence "re-checking" the ip address associated with my domain name every 5 minutes?

Comment: If they behave correctly, then yes. There's nothing to stop them from ignoring your TTL, but most well-behaved DNS servers obey the TTL value.

Answer (score 0):

You can have two identical EC2 instances. One with the old public IP where DNS record is pointing to. One with the EIP assigned. Requests should be able to access anyone of the two instances without noticing it. Your application must be able to scale horizontally. Then you change DNS record to point to EIP. Eventually, when DNS is updated, all requests to your domain will end up going to the EC2 instance with the EIP. At that moment you can stop or terminate the old EC2 instance.

Other possibility if your application cannot scale horizontally and if it is a web application, the web server in the old EC2 instance can redirect requests to the EIP. It would redirect to an IP address but it's a possibility.

Comment: yikes...  this is what I feared...  So as soon I associate an EIP with the instance it will become the "public ip"?    Could have sworn at one point in the past I had an EIP associated with the instance that was different from its public IP.  So you could actually access the server both by EIP and public ip.  I just want to be very careful here so that I don't bring down website and have to wait for propagation.

Comment: @MSchenkel, yes EIP will become the "public IP"

Answer (score 0):

If you don't use EC2-Classic instances, you can freely move the Elastic IP to any other EC2 instance without losing the EIP.

```
aws ec2 associate-address --region us-east-1 --allocation-id eipalloc-xxxxxxxxxxx --allow-reassociation --network-interface-id eni-xxxxxxxxxx
```

where eipalloc-xxxxxxxxxxx is the id of the Elastic IP and eni-xxxxx is the id of the target EC2 instance.

https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ec2-recover-ip-address/

Elastic IP addresses

It's a best practice to use an Elastic IP address. Elastic IP addresses are allocated to your account, instead of to the instance. You can associate your Elastic IP addresses to and from instances as needed.

If you release the Elastic IP address that was allocated to your account, you might be able to recover it. For more information, see Recovering an Elastic IP address.

All instances except EC2-Classic instances retain their associated Elastic IP addresses when stopped. AWS continues to bill for Elastic IP addresses associated with a stopped instance.

Note: Elastic IP addresses associated with EC2-Classic instances aren't recoverable.