# Assigning Elastic IP without loosing the domain availability on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, elastic-ip

I have an IP address for my EC2 and I set the  Domain DNS to that IP address and it works fine now. but we just found that the Public IPv4 is not permanent and we lose it by a simple restart, so we need to assign an Elastic IP to that. But by assigning and Elastic IP we lose the Public IP for the EC2 and the domain goes down till we set the domain DNS and waiting for propagation time up.

How can we manage this situation without having the downtime on the domain side?

Comment: I managed to fix the problem. based on the searches I found two solutions.

Answer (score 2):

Make a copy of your EC2 instance, attach Elastic IP to that new instance and then perform the DNS cutoff. Wait for the DNS to propagate and then shut down the old instance. You can monitor the traffic coming to your old instance to be sure that (or at least reasonably sure) that you can terminate it. Doing this, there should be no downtime.

Comment: Thank you. it looks like a solution but all the files and database are on the server. so not possible without downtime.

Answer (score 1):

DNS "propagation" is essentually a myth.  There is a delay, but it isn't due to anything properly called "propagation."  It's due to distributed caching and TTL.  It's phenomenon that's easily understood but perhaps a little difficult to explain.

Observe the TTL ("time-to-live") on your current DNS record.  Let's assume it is 3600 -- the number is in seconds, so that would be 1 hour.  The *current* value means that the *next* time you change the record, you can expect it to take *up to that long* to "propagate."

So, make a note of the value, then change the TTL to a very small number, such as 15.  After the *previous* TTL in time passes, 15 will be your *current* TTL, globally.  (If the previous value was 3600, then one hour -- 3,600 seconds -- after you change to 15 is when 15 is your new effective value, globally.)

Once this is established, you can then change your A-record to point to a new IP address, and the change will "propagate" within 15 seconds.  In fact, it will take about 35 seconds longer than this, if you are using Route 53, because Route 53 has a brief delay before changes become visible... but this strategy allows a quick change with -- mostly -- minimal disruption.

EC2 allows you hot-swap a public IP for an Elastic IP without stopping the machine, so you can take that IP and put it in DNS, then attach it to the instance, and you're done.  Within a few seconds, your DNS is correct and "propagated."  Once comfortable with the new environment, change the DNS TTL to a larger value again, to improve performance and reduce the number of queries Route 53 needs to process.

It all sounds pretty straightforward, but there's still a catch.

The catch is that anyone who has their browser open when you make the change may lose access to the site, no matter what you do, because browsers tend to cache DNS lookups, regardless of the configured TTL.  The DNS record is current and up to date, but their browser isn't looking for it.  The browser may cache the old value until closed.  Browser behavior in this regard is a bit of a wildcard.

There is an AWS service that you can use temporarily to prevent this from happening -- by exposing your site on public IPs not attached to the actual instance.  You can migrate your DNS to point there, temporarily.

Assuming it's a web site, connect an Application Load Balancer to the instance.  Switch the DNS to point to the ALB.  Wait until your web server logs show all requests are coming in through the ALB.  Then change the instance to an Elastic IP.  Since ALB connects to the instance using its *private* IP address, it will not be impacted.  Then, change the DNS to the EIP.  Again, wait until the web server logs start showing traffic coming directly to the instance, and to stop showing any traffic coming through the ALB -- the ALB logs showing no meaningful traffic.  (You can't simply use the ALB request count metrics for this, since all web servers with public IPs receive some amount of garbage traffic from people scanning the web.)  Once no traffic is coming through the ALB, delete it.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix the problem and I wanted to share it with you. based on the searches I found two solutions.

1- Adding a load balancer and attaching the EC2 to that and giving the load balancer an IP. So you can change the domain DNS to that load balancer and there will be no downtime or propagation for that. Then you can assign an elastic IP to your EC2 and again change the DNS to that IP without propagation.

2- You can do it by adding a subnet and network interface which is completely covered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33930248/possible-to-associate-elastic-ip-to-an-instance-without-immediately-losing-publi)